# What is the use of a balanced modulator?

Tags: amplitude-modulation

I am currently writing a report for university about DSB (double sideband) modulation techniques and balanced modulators. Here is the question that need to be answered:

**The balanced modulator is used for:**

- (a) For stabilization between left and right channel while in stereo mode?
- (b) To remove the phase inversion from the signal and therefore this signal can be demodulated by a detector?
- (c) It searches for balance in power between sidebands and carrier?
- (d) Needing 2 identical AM modulators?

It doesn't ask to explain the reason we give a particular answer, but I would like to hear from you an explanation.

Comment: 'None of the above' is the answer

Comment: A cursory search yields a lot of hits. Try https://wiki.analog.com/university/courses/electronics/electronics_lab_diode_ring_modulator

Comment: @Neil_UK I disagree. There is one answer that makes sense.

Comment: In stereo mode, signal MPX is DSB modulated with L-R at 38 kHz ... Other signal is L+R in low pass filter +++ Pilot 19 kHz for synchronizing demodulator and reconstructing after L and R signals. (E&EO).

Comment: @Antonio51 I'm not sure we should be offering direct answers to the OP at this point.

Comment: Hey! Welcome back, Ντίνος! Small problem: you're just forwarding your assignment to us. We don't do that here. We will help you, as soon as you ask a **precise question of your own**, designed to help *you* get further in answering the question *yourself*.

Comment: @Andyaka  Right. (a), but not concise enough for a safe choice.

Comment: And would you say @Antonio51 this is related to DSB modulation (please don't answer because it's a rhetorical question). The OP has to show effort here and not just dump homework on this site.

Comment: A very warm welcome to the site. Please note that it's a Q&A, not a discussion forum and discussion is what you've asked for. It can't be a homework-answering service or online personal tutorial. People will help you take the next step if your question shows you've already done as much as you possibly could - which yours doesn't, I'm afraid. Please edit your question and greatly improve it. Show all your own work and own findings so far in considerable detail. The better the quality of your question, the better the quality of the answers it will attract. Again, welcome.

Comment: Hum ... "stabilization between" are not the right "words" in this sentence...